# Define Struct in C

Tags: c, struct

I am reading an old hardware code, i find a weird definition of struct:

```
struct DAA_BITS {
  unsigned long  DAAON          : 1;
  unsigned long  DAARDY         : 1;
  unsigned long                 : 1;
  unsigned long  DAA_TRIM       : 5;
};
```

I have two questions:

1- What is mean the :1 like definition "unsigned long  DAAON          **: 1**;"? did its a common use?

2- In the third value of the struct, there is no name of variable, why to use that?, and how can i access this memory?

I know its looks like the code is not real, but the code is running will(i also debug the code).

Comment: The `:1`'s are bitfields and the missing name one might be for padding, because that way the first bit of `DAA_TRIM` will be in the expected place. Note that they add to 8 bits. But I honestly didn't know that you can have "*anonymous*" structure fields, so I will not answer this, let's give a chance to someone that really understands this.

Comment: Maybe the third variable is specified in such a way to complete 8 bits and shouldn't be used.

Comment: Hmm, your question was closed as I was writing an answer.  That's a shame, because I don't think any of the "duplicates" actually answer the second part of your question...  As @TomTsagk says - it's just a placeholder to pad out the structure.  You can't reference it.  I'd really strongly recommend getting *the* authoritative book on C: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29 - worth every penny, trust me :)

Comment: See http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/ "The lost art of structure packing " chapter 6 where bitfields are explained

Comment: Thank you all (@harob, TomTsagk, Wally, HaraldDutch)  , sorry for question 1(duplicate question)